# Rust: How to mock request::Result?

Tags: testing, rust, mocking

Consider the following function:

```
pub async fn api_get<T: 'static>(&self, path: &str) -> reqwest::Result<T>
where
    T: serde::de::DeserializeOwned,
{
    let url = format!("{}/{}", self.backend_url, path);
    let response = self.client.get(&url).send().await?;
    let data = response.json::<T>().await?;
    Ok(data)
}
```

How can I mock the request::Result type to return an Error type type?

I Tried the following:

```
#[tokio::test]
async fn foo_test() {
    let mock_client = HttpClient::default();

    mock_client
        .expect_api_post()
        .returning(|_, __| reqwest::Error::new(reqwest::ErrorKind::Other, "test error"));
}
```

However this does not work as the `new` method is private. So how can I mock the return type of this function?

(In this case the api_post method is declared in the impl block of the struct `HttpClient`)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use library types directly. Instead, think of libraries as nothing more but an implementation of your real need. An implementation that could change.

Thinking of libraries as mere implementations, it becomes much easier to test. It also makes program structure clearer, and less tightly coupled: instead of passing around types from `reqwest` directly, define a trait that exposes just the functionality you really need, and then use `reqwest` to implement it. Then do another stub implementation as a mock for tests (or use something like `mockall`).

Suddenly it's super easy to test components in isolation, especially in combination with composition: just pass the testee the stub implementation instead and check its behaviour.

This pattern of hiding library implementations behind your own traits also reduces inter-dependency and prevents tight coupling. Your app is no longer tied to specific libraries. Other parts of your code can only use what this part explicitly exposes.

If you ever need to replace the implementation of one part of your program, this suddenly becomes really easy.

This might sound like a lot of work and annoying and requiring writing a lot of boilerplate, but in reality it's really not bad - and I think it is worth it given the advantages. In many cases you probably really only need one or two functions. Copying the signature from the library into your trait is going to be enough in many cases. Make sure to either wrap the library's error types (maybe using `thiserror`), or use something like `anyhow` for easy catch-all error handling, otherwise the library's types will bleed out that way.

Comment: I can definitely see the value in doing it this way, although it will require some rewriting. Thank you :)